# Is there any clue as to who the owner of the "Elite Knight Armour" Set might be?

Tags: dark-souls

In Dark Souls, whenever you find set items on a corpse, they can be sometimes linked to other NPCs in the game.

Some examples for this are

- Black Iron Tarkus: After you summon him to fight the Iron Golem, along the path into Anor Londo, you find a shattered window, revealing a path along the rafters of a large building. Again, later you find an entrance to the ground floor of the same building, and in the back corner, a corpse, with the Black Iron Set.
- Lautrec of Carim: If you follow his storyline, you end up invading him before your fight with Ornstein & Smough; which you can then find a corpse carrying the Set of Favour. Again, presumably this corpse is meant to be Lautrec.
- (Unnamed) Sealer: you can find the Crimson set in Blighttown, and if you follow the lore, this set apparently belonged to one of the four Sealers that flooded New Londo to seal the Darkwraiths away. This Healer ventured down through Blighttown, and eventually succumbed to the poison, and died.
- Laurentius of the Great Swamp: Once you complete his storyline, you can find him down in Blighttown, hollowed. Again, you can find a corpse near the location where he attacked you, carrying the Pyromancer Set.

So is there any clue as to who the owner of the Elite Knight Armour set is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [item description](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/elite-knight-set) is pretty clear on it:

```
Armor of a nameless knight, perhaps an elite
knight of Astora, based on the fire-warding
heraldic symbol on its blue surcoat.

Although he was loath to give up on his
Undead mission, he perished at the Undead
Asylum, and went Hollow.
```

It belongs to guy who drops you key and gives estus flask at the beginning of the game. Later you could find him hollowed there.

Looks like that guy name is [Oscar](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/oscar-knight-of-astora).

Comment: So it is "Oscar"?

Comment: Wow, he is listed on wiki as Oscar, yes. But I can't remember he ever introduced himself in game. I will add link to his page into answer.

Comment: So then why do you find his armor all the way in darkroot forest and not in the undead asylum?

Comment: @Pyritie, you know, 'time is convoluted in Lordran'. I don't know, may be item placement was somehow related to unused storyline - there is some event with Oscar in Darkroot Forest in unused content - http://darksouls.wikidot.com/unused-content#toc27

Comment: @arghtype yeah, he was origibally meant to be the equivalent of Solaire in the game, but his storyline got scrapped.